# How to get the counts/frequencies of values in a table?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, unpivot

I have the problem that I need to get the number of occurences / the counts or frequencies of values in a table. However, I cannot give the categories before, so in opposite to countif I cannot specify a specific value, as this needs to be done from the table. I have a whole table, not just a column. The picture shows a reduced example:

[image: example]

The result I need would look like the following (I counted manually, hope I did not do a mistake):

[image: result]

It is not needed to calculate empty cells.

For the starting point I am ok with not specifiying if there is a difference between lowercase and uppercase (so L and l for example). This can be calculated separately or as the same. Later on it would be good to be able to choose this as an option. (I could use lowercase function and refer to this column and fill another column with the values, however the original data is way too large.). My problem is now that I am not able to do this "simple" task. I found a solution for a single column, using a matrix function with countif:

[image: matrix function]

{=countif(A21:A27;A21:A27)}

This does not work for a whole table. My original data is too large to do any task manually and repeat this for each column or rearrange the data manually from table to one single column.

Unfortunately I am limited to Excel and/or Excel VBA. I cannot use any other tool. I am happy with an excel solution, if there is a way to do it in VBA I am also very ok with it, however for this I cannot give a proof that I tried it, because I don't have an idea how to program this and I am not advanced enough in coding VBA.

Comment: Can you use a pivot table?

Comment: I agree with @Warcupine that you should be able to use a pivot table

Comment: @Warcupine No, I thought the same, however Pivot table does not work in this specific case!

Comment: @Warcupine pray tell, how would a pivot table work on that data?

Comment: @MilesFett How would a pivot table work on that data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through PowerQuery

Sample data:

[image]

My Excel is in Dutch so excuse me for making some translation errors. It should still point you in the right direction:

- 1: Select all data > Data Tab > Transform > From Table/Range > Choose No headers
- 2: In PQ select all 4 columns > Transform Tab > Unpivot all columns
- 3: Select value column > Transform Tab > Pivot Table > Ok
- 4: Select all columns > Transform Tab > Unpivot all columns again
- 5: Exit PowerQuery and confirm to save your edition.

Result:

[image]

- Will exclude empty cells
- Will distinguish between upper and lower case

Comment: Thanks @teylyn, I just hope I mentioned the proper english equivalents to my Dutch version :)

Comment: @JvdV Thanks for your good answer! This does answer the question. I just want to note that this requires PowerQuery to be installed or that one has a version where one can install it. If someone works in a company where excel is an older version or where it is not allowed to install PowerQuery, this does not work. Luckily, I have PowerQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Analyzing this data is easiest if it is in one column. You can use Power Query (Get & Transform) for that. Load the data into the Power Query Editor, keep only column 1. Repeat and keep only column 2, repeat for columns 3 and 4.

Next, append the columns, so you have one column of data.

[image]

Now you can either load this data into the data model and THEN it's easy to build a pivot table. Blank cells can be removed in the Power Query or by filtering the pivot table.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It would do the job, however my data is simply too large (too many columns to do it manually for each). So in my case this approach would not work.